# Unable to retrieve field values in popup when using tinymce editor

Tags: jquery

Am using tinymce editor with in popup. When am trying to get all field values using name attribute of html am not able to get field values. It returns just empty object only.It returns always like this.
 [object Object] : ""
 Please suggest any solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this text box inside update panel?

Comment: Am appending that editor into textArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var html = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('<%= txtComments.ClientID %>').getBody().innerHTML;
```